# How do we get the gain and cut off frequency values of the active low-pass filter?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, low-pass, math

I'm trying to find the **gain** and **cut off frequency** values myself. But I can't get the same result when fiddling with the formula. The last screenshot is from my own solution. Where am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: On the 2nd line, the R1 multiplies through the denominator not the numerator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've highlighted the mistake in red below:

[image]

You did get the numerator correctly written out just prior to the mistake. I've highlighted that portion in green. But you should have used \$\frac1{R_1}\$ as the multiplier for the numerator to get \$\frac{R_2}{R_1}\$ in the numerator, not \$R_1\,R_2\$.

In Python/sympy, you could:

```
def par(a,b): return a*b/(a+b)
simplify(-par(r2,1/s/c1)/r1)

-r2/(r1*(c1*r2*s + 1))
```

Which is the same as:

```
-(r2/r1)/(c1*r2*s + 1)
```

### Added

The gain \$K\$ is found when you place the above into a *standard form* (there's more than one.) One standard form for a low-pass is \$K\frac{\omega_{_0}}{s+\omega_{_0}}\$ and another standard form is \$K\frac{1}{\left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}\right)+1}\$. Either way, the \$K\$ will be the same and it collects whatever is left over once the standard fraction form is constructed.

I can easily see that I can isolate \$s\$ in the denominator by dividing through by \$R_2\,C_1\$. So I'll pick the first standard form that I mentioned, to keep things easy:

$$\begin{align*}
H\left(s\right)&= -1\cdot \frac{\frac{R_2}{R_1}}{R_2\,C_1\,s+1}\cdot\frac{\frac1{R_2\,C_1}}{\frac1{R_2\,C_1}}
\\\\
&= -1\cdot \frac{\frac{R_2}{R_1}\cdot \frac1{R_2\,C_1}}{s+\frac1{R_2\,C_1}}
\\\\
&=-\frac{R_2}{R_1}\cdot \frac{ \frac1{R_2\,C_1}}{s+\frac1{R_2\,C_1}}
\end{align*}$$

Just by observation \$K=-\frac{R_2}{R_1}\$ and \$\omega_{_0}=\frac1{R_2\,C_1}\$. (Note that I include the negative sign in \$K\$, not external to it.)

The standard forms have reasoning behind them. First off, a note about \$s=\sigma+j\,\omega\$, which is a complex number. Multiplication in the complex domain involves both scaling and rotation, unlike multiplication in the real domain which *only* involves scaling. You need to get used to that idea and own it. It's important. Second, complex domain values can be plotted either in cartesian (\$x+j\,y\$) or polar notation (\$r+j\,\theta\$.)

Electronics uses Euler's form, though, which neatly isolates the scaling and rotation behavior: \$e^{\sigma+j\,\theta}=e^\sigma\left[\cos\left(\theta\right)+j\sin\left(\theta\right)\right]\$, where the earlier \$r=e^\sigma\$.

Finally, everything in electronics involves time \$t\$ and its inverse, frequency \$f\$. To put frequency into angular frequency, \$\omega=2\pi\,f\$ (in radians per second) and so to get radians find that \$\theta=\omega\cdot t\$. The scaling also occurs over time, as well.

So if \$s=\sigma+j\omega\$ then \$e^{s\,t}=e^{\sigma\,t}\left[\cos\left(\theta=\omega\,t\right)+j\sin\left(\theta=\omega\,t\right)\right]\$. From here, you can readily see that if \$\sigma\gt0\$ then there is a very serious problem as time proceeds, as the scaling factor explodes towards infinity. If you think about what happens in this case, you can imagine a rotating vector whose length is growing ever larger as time proceeds, tracing out an outward spiral on the chart. "Spiraling out of control" so to speak. This is also a problem in electronics. Mostly bad news. Also, if \$\sigma\lt0\$ then the scaling factor reduces towards zero as time proceeds. Tracing the vector in this case would be an inward spiral towards the origin. That tends to be more acceptable. And when \$\sigma=0\$, exactly, then \$e^{\sigma=0}=1\$ and the focus is then entirely on the rotation part of Euler's and the vector length doesn't change. It just spins around and around, tracing out a circle over time.

So when someone says \$H\left(j\omega\right)\$ they are implying the idea of setting \$\sigma=0\$ so as to focus on the rotation rate behavior (frequency response) of the system. The frequency response is often the more important perspective to consider.

At DC, \$\omega=0\$ (and \$s=0\$) and both \$K\frac{\omega_{_0}}{s+\omega_{_0}}\$ and \$K\frac{1}{\left(\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}\right)+1}\$ reduce to \$K\$. So \$K\$ is the near-DC gain of the low-pass. For passive low-pass, this will be \$K=1\$. But for active systems such as yours, it can be different.

Comment: Thanks. I get same equation affer change that but I don't understand how we determine K and wc values.

Comment: @XcellentEEE I added some discussion.

Answer (score 1):

The error is somewhere on the second line.

The first equation looks correct, as at DC it is just -R2/R1 as expected.

The second equation at DC will equate to -R1R2 so it must be wrong.